# why is android:layout_above doesn't work in

Tags: java, android, layout

I have this layout

```
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/comments_list" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_editText" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/search_btn" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/search_btn"/>
    <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:hint="enter phone"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blocked"
            android:id="@+id/isBlocked_cb"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_above="@+id/comments_list"
            android:checked="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="search"
            android:id="@+id/search_btn"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/phone_editText"
            android:layout_above="@+id/comments_list"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:onClick="foo"/>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/comment_text"
                android:hint="enter comment"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <Button style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Add" android:id="@+id/add_btn"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment_text" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/comment_text"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="0px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want `bottom_container` to be below my ListView

but in the simulator they seems one above the other:

[image]

Comment: what is the actual problem ? question ?, things you have tried ..

Comment: sorry. the image wasn't upload

Comment: layout_alignParentBottom on the bottom_container align bottom to the parent relativeLayout, should try to remove this

Answer (score 0):

Your question it's pretty incomplete, but I see some potential error in your xml about "above"

For example

```
android:layout_above="@+id/comments_list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:onClick="foo"/>
```

This is an error, you can not declare align parent top and end togheter... and in any case, If I'm right, those ovverride layout_above.